# Phaser 3 How to fill Phaser.Curves.Path with color?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

**Hey!** Could anyone help me please, I have some troubles with rendering custom `Path` to `RenderTexture`

**How to fill the Path with color??**

I have prepared sandbox example for my problem: https://stackblitz.com/edit/set-bounce-phaser-3-so-ixfkeq
Here is the code sample:

```
function create() {
  this.add.image(400, 300, 'sky');

  graphics = new Phaser.GameObjects.Graphics(this);
  graphics.lineStyle(4, 0x00ff00);
  graphics.fillStyle(0x00ff00); // how to fill it??

  rt = this.add.renderTexture(100, 100, 100, 100).setOrigin(0.5);

  var circle = this.add
    .circle(0, 0, 50, 0xff7e00)
    .setAlpha(0.8)
    .setVisible(false);

  rt.draw(circle, 50, 50);

  // This is just example, I need complex path with curves
  const path = new Phaser.Curves.Path(); // how to fill it??
  path.lineTo(50, 0);
  path.lineTo(50, 50);
  path.lineTo(0, 50);
  path.closePath();
  path.draw(graphics);
  rt.draw(graphics, 25, 25);
}
```

With this code I can see filled circle and only stroke for the Path

[image]

What did I miss ?

Comment: how is this related to pixi.js? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is found!

```
graphics.fillPoints(path.getPoints())
```